# get_the_excerpt() with fallback like the_excerpt()

Tags: filters, excerpt

You know when using `the_excerpt()` and no "excerpt" is set on a post it automatically uses the first 50 words or so.

Is the same also possible when using `get_the_excerpt()`

For instance I'm using `get_the_excerpt()` like this …

```
$return .= sprintf('
                <li>
                    <div class="title"><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a><span class="goto">a</span></div>
                    <div class="project-description">%3$s</div>
                </li>',
                get_permalink( get_the_ID() ),
                get_the_title(),
                get_the_excerpt()
        );
```

However if no excerpt is set, the `get_the_excerpt()` function doesn't show a fallback (the first 50 or so words). Any idea how to make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `the_excerpt()` is only a echo of the function `get_the_excerpt()`:

```
function the_excerpt() {
    echo apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt());
}
```

If you like a fall back for no input the excerpt meta box, then create a text from the content - `get_the_content()`. You can use the core function `wp_trim_words()` for set the counter for words and easy to set a text from all content.
A example:

```
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = esc_attr( strip_tags( stripslashes( $excerpt ) ) );
$excerpt = wp_trim_words( $excerpt, $num_words = 55, $more = NULL );
```

Comment: thank you, but how do I use that in my sample code above. How is `the_excerpt` used if an excerpt is set, but the stripped/trimmed content used when no excerpt is set? What is the cleanes solution for that?

Comment: Write you a custom function, there check for the excerpt and if empty, then use my example. This custom function include in your `sprintf()`.

Comment: How do you check the excerpt is empty?

Comment: Use the function [`get_the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) , there have a return, no echo. A example `$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); if ( $my_excerpt != '' ) { // todo }`