# Using get_the_excerpt() Before The Loop

Tags: loop, excerpt

I tried echoing `get_the_excerpt(1)`, on different locations outside the loops:

- somewhere in `footer.php`
- somewhere in `header.php`

(The post with ID 1 has no defined excerpt btw, so I was hoping for the auto-generated ones to came out)

---

The one in `footer.php` printed the stuff just fine, but the one in `header.php` somehow printed nothing (blank).

May I ask for simple explanation on how such thing could happen? And a workaround to make auto-generated excerpt printed correctly on both locations.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you use a secondary (custom) loop in the main template? In that case you'll have to call `wp_reset_postdata();` before you can use `get_the_excerpt()` in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

So you are basically also looking for a fallback in case your excerpt is empty? I suppose this question/answer could be helpful for you: "[get_the_excerpt() with fallback like the_excerpt()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87620/get-the-excerpt-with-fallback-like-the-excerpt)". It describes, how to build your own "excerpt" in case there is none – like this:

```
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = esc_attr( strip_tags( stripslashes( $excerpt ) ) );
$excerpt = wp_trim_words( $excerpt, $num_words = 55, $more = NULL );
```

In your case you would probably add the ID to it: `$excerpt = get_the_content(1);`. I don't know if your SE privileges allow this, but  should probably add "*I'm looking for a solution for when has (the article) no defined excerpt / the post_excerpt is empty*" to your question to clarify what you are actually looking for…

Answer (score 0):

Outside the loop you could try something like this:

```
$post_id = 1;
$myexcerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $post_id));

echo $myexcerpt;
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it's giving me blanks on both locations.

The post have no defined excerpt, so `post_excerpt` is empty, which is probably the reason why your code is giving blanks...

Comment: You have to change it to the post that has the excerpt.  Can you test with one that actually has an excerpt?

Comment: both your code and simple `get_the_excerpt(1)` gives the right stuff if the `post_excerpt` is not empty. But unfortunately, I'm looking for solution for when has no defined excerpt (`post_excerpt` is empty).

Comment: What do you want it to do when excerpt is empty?